# Placing a Banner ad so that it sits below and seperate from ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, banner-ads

I have a ViewPager with 3 Fragments,

[image]

At the bottom of each fragment I have placed a Banner ad.

What I would like is to have one banner ad at the bottom of the entire view, instead of one in each fragment

[image]

This way I only have to load one ad, and it is always placed at the bottom of the screen.

My ViewPager Activity is where I think the Banner Ad should go, but I don't know how to move it into there.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">   
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

ad thats currently in the Frags

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adMainViewTrial"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="My Id" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

I hope I've made sense of this. I still only have a tenuous grasp on what i'm doing here, so all help is certainly appreciated.

[image]

Heres a picture of my app as is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check it.

> My ViewPager Activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adMainViewTrial"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="My Id" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can initialize ads in `MyViewPagerActivity`.

I hope it will help you.